# WCF: Prioritise sending messages across different interfaces

Tags: .net, wcf

We have a WCF 4.6 server supporting several interfaces. For simplicity, let’s assume that all methods of all interfaces are one way. The requests are generally handled with ConcurrencyMode = Multiple both on client and server sides.

There is one interface of lower priority, while all the other interfaces are of higher priority. This means that once a client wants to call a method of the lower priority interface, it must check first whether any methods of high priority interfaces are currently being processed. What does this mean? From what I gleaned on some forum follows that when a one-way method is called, the message is either immediately sent across the wire or is placed in the WCF internal queue if another message is being sent at that very moment. Control is immediately returned to the caller (unless the queue is full).

The question is, **is there a way for the caller to determine that the WCF internal output queue (or queues) is empty?** The rationale is that we want to send the lower priority message ML1 only if it is empty. If it is not empty then ML1 will be placed in the queue after some another message MH1:

```
MH1, ML1
```

While MH1 is waiting to be processed/is being processed, another higher priority message MH2 might be handed to WCF for sending, in which case it will be placed in the queue after the low priority message ML1:

```
MH1, ML1, MH2
```

This we would like to avoid.
I realise that even if we’ve checked that the queue is empty, it might become non-empty just before we send the lower priority message – but that’s fine, we can live with that, as it won’t happen very often.

I’ve read a few discussions on the need to prioritise the requests at the business level, but if the said above about the WCF internal queue is correct, that would not help, since even if we know that there’s no outstanding higher priority requests at the business level, we can’t be certain such requests are not waiting in the queue for their turn to be sent. Nor WCF Routing seems to do what we need.
Also, we are limited to only using a single port per server, due to business considerations.